# SQL foreign key to a non existent table field

Tags: sql

i'm just starting with SQL, i have an assignement to do that involves a relational scheme to SQL tables.

I have a big doubt on how to represent the following:
I have the table "Original" that is represented by the following SQL:

```
create table Original (
  idB       char(10)      not null unique,
  tituloM   varchar(255)  not null, 
  primary key (idB, tituloM),
  foreign key (idB, tituloM) references Musica on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

I now have to represent the table "Live" that has the following relational representation:
Live(idB; tituloM; data; hora; tituloMO), where `idB` and `tituloMO` are foreign keys to "Original". My doubt is, we don't have a "tituloMO" in the "Original" table. How can i represent this ? Currently my "Original" table looks like this:

```
create table Live (
  idB      char(10)  not null unique,
  tituloM  varchar(255)  not null,
  /* date goes here */
  /* time goes here */
  tituloMO  varchar(255) not null,
  primary key (idB, tituloM),
  foreign key (idB, tituloM) references Musica on delete cascade on update cascade,
  foreign key (idB, data, hora) references Concerto on delete cascade on update cascade,
  foreign key (idB, tituloMO)
);
```

How can I represent the `tituloMO` field correctly?

Comment: Please do not post code that uses tabs - it can be a real pain to reformat.  Also, sign off's like "thanks in advance" are not necessary (besides a waste of screen real estate) - that is what selecting an answer and upvoting is for.

Comment: What DBMS do you use? Your `foreign key` looks like they miss the parent table fields. Is that really allowed in any DBMS?

Comment: Yes, i was indeed missing the parent table fields. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a `FOREIGN KEY` reference, you don't need for the corresponding columns to have same names, only compatible datatypes.

So, your constraints would be:

```
create table Original (
  idB       char(10)      not null unique,
  tituloM   varchar(255)  not null, 
  primary key (idB, tituloM),
  foreign key (idB, tituloM) 
    references Musica (idB, tituloM)         --- you need these, too
      on delete cascade 
      on update cascade
);

create table Live (
  idB      char(10)  not null unique,
  tituloM  varchar(255)  not null,
  /* date goes here */
  /* time goes here */
  tituloMO  varchar(255) not null,
  primary key (idB, tituloM),
  foreign key (idB, tituloM) 
    references Musica (idB, tituloM)         --- and these
      on delete cascade 
      on update cascade,
  foreign key (idB, data, hora) 
    references Concerto (idB, data, hora)    --- and these
      on delete cascade 
      on update cascade,
  foreign key (idB, tituloMO)
    references Original (idB, tituloM)       --- this is an assumption
      on delete cascade                      --- based on the datatypes
      on update cascade,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what the `tituloMO` field corresponds in the `Original` table. It does not need to be the same name.

You could for example map `Live.tituloMO` to `Original.tituloM`

I don't know what DBMS you have, your foreign key syntax looks like it is missing the parent table fields.

This is how you would type in Oracle.

```
foreign key (idB, tituloMO) references Original(idB, tituloM) on delete...
```

Comment: Yes, i was indeed missing the parent table fields. Thanks.